# PhoneGap - OnDeviceReady method not getting called

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing my first application in phonegap (android).

## index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Device Properties Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        alert('code: 1');
        // Wait for Cordova to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        alert('code: 2');
        var watchID = null;
        alert('code: 3');
        // Cordova is ready
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            // Update every 3 seconds
            alert('code: 4');
            var options = { frequency: 3000 };
            watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
        }

        // onSuccess Geolocation
        //
        function onSuccess(position) {
            alert('code: 5');
            var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
            element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude      + '<br />' +
                                'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude     + '<br />' +
                                '<hr />'      + element.innerHTML;
        }

        // clear the watch that was started earlier
        // 
        function clearWatch() {
            alert('code: 6');
            if (watchID != null) {
                navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
                watchID = null;
            }
        }

        // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
        //
        function onError(error) {
          alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p id="geolocation">Watching geolocation...</p>
        <button onclick="clearWatch();">Clear Watch</button>     
      </body>
    </html>
```

Here onDeviceReady method is not getting called. Kindly help me understand what i am missing.

I have added these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

in manifest.xml file.

Comment: I am getting till  alert('code: 3') but ondevicereadymethod is not getting called. I dont know what i am missing. Please help me on the same.

Comment: have you tried the example android app comes with the cordova 1.7?

Comment: hi user623517, i tried u r example and it worked very well. why dont you try on another device and then update us abt u r prooblem

Comment: Hi NejiHyunga ... Which device are you using ? I tried samsung galaxy Ace and Google nexux ics but ondeviceready method is not getting called.

Comment: Problem was not device specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow it this way and it should be working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Cordova Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Call onDeviceReady when Cordova is loaded.
    //
    // At this point, the document has loaded but cordova-1.7.0.js has not.
    // When Cordova is loaded and talking with the native device,
    // it will call the event `deviceready`.
    //
    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    // Cordova is loaded and it is now safe to make calls Cordova methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use the Cordova API
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Also check the [Android example folder](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/tree/master/lib/android/example) in the Cordova 1.7 download.

Comment: I missed this method ... function onLoad() { document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false); } ... so, OnDeviceReady Method was not getting called. I missed this. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Link is broken Kindly fix it.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who is still in trouble looking for solution - check the alternative .js files imported into your index.html, for example the index.js might have its own device ready call and function, therefore blocking your custom one.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for my one!!
It's really simple problem on acquaintance.

We usually develop one cordova(phonegap) project, and then copy all related files (/www) to another one.
but I realized Cordova file (cordova-2.2.0 now) is different between platforms.

**Do not copy even cordova file.
Use original example one on the platform.**

not sure for every case. is this helpful? :)